# How to make a program perform a certain action only a given percentage of times?

Tags: python, random

I don't think the title is all that clear.

Suppose I have a Python program that opens http://www.google.com

How do I make it so that it only opens 23% of time, 37% of time, 12% of time, etc? In other words, I want to make my Python program open the google.com sometimes, and not other times.

I realize I could technically make a list with a few empty elements and one call to the function that would open the web page, but I would ideally be able to change the "percentages" all the time.

If the question is still unclear, let me know.

Comment: `import random; if random.random() < 0.23: doStuff()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Generate a random number.  Often those are in [0, 1).
2. If the number is less than the percentage you want (0.37 == 37%), do the action.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I had a brainfart - did not think of it this way at all.